# I need the English word whose meaning is "someone who appears that one can compete with, but is actually beyond competition"

Tags: single-word-requests

I had heard the word long back, but now I don't remember it. It would be great if someone can tell me the word.

Comment: You may be looking for the idiom "[*a dark horse*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=a+dark+horse)".

Answer (score 3):

Or a "ringer" — e.g. someone entered surreptitiously in an amateur competition who is actually a professional.